# Play - How to use different configuration files for Dev/Prod?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

I have a project with the following configuration

- `Commons.conf`
- `Application.conf` for development
- `Production.conf` for production

Both `application.conf` and `production.conf` include `commons.conf`

I have to build the application using dist task to generate the zip file, then start it using the `projectname.bat` file provided.

I added `javaOptions ++= Seq("-Dconfig.file=conf/production.conf")` in build.sbt but it seem that did not working. I cannot launch the application on command line because i did want it to be done automatically. What's the better way to do separate `.conf` file configuration for development and production and have `dist` task taking the production ones?

Comment: "I cannot launch the application on command line because i did want it to be done automatically" - Can you define what "automatically" is?

Comment: Double click on the bat script that automatically launch the JVM. The only way to pass parameters to JVM seems to be to edit the .bat itself on line 127 adding it after 
`set _JAVA_OPTS=!_JAVA_OPTS! !_JAVA_PARAMS!`

Comment: You need to look into how to execute the bat file on the command line - it is much better practice for you since you will likely have to deploy to a remote machine at some point in your career  (whether it be windows or *nix) and will need to use the command line.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On startup of your application, Play is automatically configured to load `application.conf` from the classpath. To override this with an alternative you need to specify this on startup.

Note that whether you are deploying to Windows and starting the app with a `.bat`, or Linux with a `.sh` you are usually executing that file as follows:-

```
$ target/universal/stage/bin/<project-name>
```

The above will execute your `.bat` file (if you are on Microsoft that is).

#### Specifying an alternative config file (couple of options)

So if you want to have separate configuration files for prod/dev then use the default `application.conf` for dev and use a `production.conf` for prod.

If you put `application.conf` inside `conf` then you would specify it as follows:-

```
$ /path/to/bin/<project-name> -Dconfig.resource=production.conf
```

If `application.conf` is not packaged with your app (ie. you have not put it in `conf` then you need to specify full path using.

```
$ target/universal/stage/bin/<project-name> -Dconfig.file=/full/path/to/conf/production.conf
```

#### An alternative approach (inheriting and overriding application.conf)

Include `application.conf` in `prod.conf` and just override what you need to for prod
Note that you can include configuration inside another, so what I usually do is specify a `prod.conf` like this:-

```
include "application.conf"

key.to.override=blah
```

Then specify `prod.conf` when you start the app and `application.conf` will automatically be included. You can then just specify the properties in `prod.conf` that override those in `application.conf` for your production environment.

#### More

Not that you can also use system properties and environment variables to override settings in `application.conf`. I encourage you to take some time to read [the docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ProductionConfiguration) to understand the options more fully.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it two ways:

1. If your package contains the configuration files:

`$ <path_to_your_executable_file> -Dconfig.resource=<name_of_your_conf_file>`

This will search for the configuration file in the application classpath, and and all such files should be in the `conf` directory before packaging.

2. If you want to provide a completely alternate file which is not packaged with the application:

`$ <path_to_your_executable_file> -Dconfig.file=<path_to_your_conf_file>`

If you look at the contents of the zip file, you'll see `bin` and `conf` directories. `bin` contains the executables and `conf` contains the configuration files. So note that the configuration files are packaged separately.

Answer (score 1):

In Play Framework 2.5.x you can run the project with the `sbt` command specifying the configuration file:

`$ sbt '; set javaOptions += "-Dconfig.file=conf/integration.conf"; run'`

You can launch the tests:

`$ sbt '; set javaOptions += "-Dconfig.file=conf/integration.conf"; test'`

Or use `testOnly`:

`$ sbt '; set javaOptions += "-Dconfig.file=conf/integration.conf"; testOnly Integration*'`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using activator then use: activator run -Dconfig.file=conf/auxiliary.conf

If you are using sbt then use: sbt '; set javaOptions += "-Dconfig.file=conf/auxiliary.conf"; run'