# Play! 2.x - disable routes for Production

Tags: scala, playframework-2.5

In the `conf/routes` file, I want to disable a set of routes

```
# disable debug routes
GET     /debug-attributes        controllers.TagsController.debugTags(lang: String ?= "en-US",url: String ?= "")
```

So far, I can override configuration values so that my controller will return a 404 code in production behaving as if the route doesn't exist. ( paragraph : "see how to" )

Is there a way to disable directly the routes or even use different dev/prod `conf/routes` file ?

**See how to Debug/Production configs**

[Play - How to use different configuration files for Dev/Prod?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40998441/play-how-to-use-different-configuration-files-for-dev-prod)

Comment: @AndriyKuba closest to what I was looking. Спасибо