# local conf play framework

Tags: scala, playframework

I have application.conf

```
{
 name {
   postgres {
      host = ""
      username = ""
      password = ""
            }
     }
}
```

And I want to add my local.conf

```
{
 name {
   postgres {
      host = "blabla"
      username = "aa"
      password = "bb"
            }
     }
}
```

**name.postgres.host.override = ""** - doesn't work

Comment: How are you loading your `local.conf`at runtime? Like this? `$ /path/to/bin/<project-name> -Dconfig.resource=local.conf`

Comment: @Nio i just put it into app/conf/local.conf. ANd I need to have my local.conf inside my project tree

Comment: Hi, have a read of the docs - https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ConfigFile#Configuration-file-syntax-and-features Play wont just load any xxx.conf, it just loads - by convention - `application.conf`. You can specify custom conf files but you need to tell Play what it needs to load at runtime. See these resources - https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ConfigFile#Specifying-an-alternative-configuration-file, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40998441/play-how-to-use-different-configuration-files-for-dev-prod/40998985#40998985

Comment: Why can't you use the `conf` directory?

Comment: @Nio I find answer by use custom settings reader. Cant use conf direct, couz my app conf is on git, and my local is just local)

Answer (score 2):

In your `application.conf`, it will remain the same:

```
{
 name {
   postgres {
      host = ""
      username = ""
      password = ""
            }
     }
}
```

And in your `local.conf`, you should include `application.conf` like this:

```
include "application.conf"

{
 name {
   postgres {
      host = "blabla"
      username = "aa"
      password = "bb"
            }
     }
}
```

When running the sbt you should specifically mention to load `local.conf` like this (Or else `application.conf` will get loaded by default):

```
sbt run -Dconfig.resource=local.conf
```

With that, `local.conf` will be extended from `application.conf`. The value from `local.conf` will be picked if there is any key that is exists in both files.

Now, you would get:

```
name.postgres.host=blabla
```

Answer (score 0):

you can include a conf file in a another conf file like this :

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2hw1.png)

this will automatically override variables.