# Cannot run tests on h2 in-memory database, rather it runs on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, playframework, h2, play-slick, slick-pg

*(I have multiple related questions, so I highlight them as bold)*

I have a [play app](https://github.com/YikSanChan/play-slick-todos).

- play: 2.6.19
- scala: 2.12.6
- h2: 1.4.197
- postgresql: 42.2.5
- play-slick/play-slick-evolutions: 3.0.1
- slick-pg: 0.16.3

I am adding a test for DAO, and I believe it should run on an h2 in-memory database that is created when tests start, cleared when tests end.

However, my test always runs on PostgreSQL database I configure and use.

```
# application.conf
slick.dbs.default.profile="slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile$"
slick.dbs.default.db.driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
slick.dbs.default.db.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"
```

Here is my test `test/dao/TodoDAOImplSpec.scala`.

```
package dao

import play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder
import play.api.test.{Injecting, PlaySpecification, WithApplication}

class TodoDAOImplSpec extends PlaySpecification {
  val conf = Map(
    "slick.dbs.test.profile" -> "slick.jdbc.H2Profile$",
    "slick.dbs.test.db.driver" -> "org.h2.Driver",
    "slick.dbs.test.db.url" -> "jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=PostgreSQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=FALSE"
  )
  val fakeApp = new GuiceApplicationBuilder().configure(conf).build()
  //val fakeApp = new GuiceApplicationBuilder().configure(inMemoryDatabase()).build()
  //val fakeApp = new GuiceApplicationBuilder().configure(inMemoryDatabase("test")).build()
  "TodoDAO" should {
    "returns current state in local pgsql table" in new WithApplication(fakeApp) with Injecting {
      val todoDao = inject[TodoDAOImpl]
      val result = await(todoDao.index())
      result.size should_== 0
    }
  }
}
```

For `fakeApp`, I try all three, but none of them work as expected - my test still runs on my local PostgreSQL table (in which there are 3 todo items), so the test fails.

What I have tried/found:

First, `inMemoryDatabase()` simply returns a `Map("db.<name>.driver"->"org.h2.Driver", "db.<name>.url"->""jdbc:h2:mem:play-test-xxx")`, which looks very similar to my own `conf` map. However, there are 2 main differeneces:

- `inMemoryDatabase` uses `db.<name>.xxx` while my `conf` map uses `slick.dbs.<name>.db.xxx`. **Which one should be correct?**

Second, rename `conf` map's keys to "slick.dbs.default.profile", "slick.dbs.default.db.driver" and "slick.dbs.default.db.url" will throw error.

```
[error] p.a.d.e.DefaultEvolutionsApi - Unknown data type: "status_enum"; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE todo ADD COLUMN status status_enum NOT NULL [50004-197] [ERROR:50004, SQLSTATE:HY004]

cannot create an instance for class dao.TodoDAOImplSpec

  caused by @79bg46315: Database 'default' is in an inconsistent state!
```

The finding is interesting - is it related to my use of PostgreSQL ENUM type and [slick-pg](https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg)? (See [slick-pg issue with h2](https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg/issues/160)). **Does it mean this is the right configuration for running h2 in-memory tests?** If so, the question becomes [How to fake PostgreSQL ENUM in h2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7988599/7550592).

Third, I follow [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40998441/play-how-to-use-different-configuration-files-for-dev-prod), run `sbt '; set javaOptions += "-Dconfig.file=conf/application-test.conf"; test'` with a test configuration file `conf/application-test.conf`:

```
include "application.conf"

slick.dbs.default.profile="slick.jdbc.H2Profile$"
slick.dbs.default.db.driver="org.h2.Driver"
slick.dbs.default.db.url="jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=PostgreSQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=FALSE"
```

Not surprisingly, I get the same error as the 2nd trial.

It seems to me that the 2nd and 3rd trials point to the right direction (Will work on this). **But why must we set `name` to `default`?** Any other better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In play the default database is **default**. You could however change that to any other database name to want, but then you need to add the database name as well. For example, I want to have a `comment` database that has the `user` table:

```
CREATE TABLE comment.User(
id                      int(250)         NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
username                varchar(255), 
comment                 varchar(255), 
PRIMARY KEY             (id));
```

Then I need to have the configuration of it to connect to it (add it to the `application.conf` file):

```
db.comment.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/comment"
db.comment.username=admin-username
db.comment.password="admin-password"
```

You could have the `test` database for your testing as mentioned above and use it within your test.

**Database Tests Locally**: Why not have the database, in local, as you have in production? The data is not there and running the test on local does not touch the production database; why you need an extra database?

**Inconsistent State**: This is when the MYSQL you wrote, changes the state of the current database within the database, that could be based on creation of a new table or when you want to delete it.

Also `status_enum` is not recognizable as a MySQL command obviously. Try the commands you want to use in MySQL console if you are not sure about it.

Comment: I use PostgreSQL instead of MySQL. The rest of the answer helps. I finally turn to test with another PostgreSQL database.

Comment: [My diff](https://github.com/YikSanChan/play-slick-todos/commit/487623189148eee590fe0ba0a9c81e85adec8974) to solve this problem may help