# Build Scala Play app using different config file

Tags: scala, build, playframework, sbt

I have a Scala Play application builded using sbt.

When I build the package using `sbt dist` command, this will result in an archive deployed in `/target/universal` path. The problem is that I have 3 configuration files:

- application.conf
- dev.conf
- prod.conf

If I try to run `sbt dist -Dconfig.resource=prod.conf`, I get an error:

```
[error] Expected ID character
[error] Not a valid command: prod (similar: stopProd, runProd, reload)
[error] Expected project ID
[error] Expected configuration
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Expected key
[error] Not a valid key: prod (similar: products, projectId, project-id)
[error] prod.conf
```

Even if I use quotes, or `-Dconfig.file`, the result is the same. Where am I wrong? thanks

> late edit:

`sbt dist` will build the `bin/*.bat` files, but the rest of files will remain unbuilded. So, I think if I go for this `.zip` solution, the package will be the same for all environment types (dev, stage, prod), but I can choose the config file when I run the command to start application:

for example, for prod I can use:

```
nohup ./app-name-1.0/bin/app-name -J-Xms8g -J-Xmx8g -Dconfig.resource=prod.conf -Dhttp.port=7777</dev/null>> logfile.log 2>&1 &
```

where `-Dconfig.resource=prod.conf` make what I want in this post.

Comment: This may help a little https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40998441/play-how-to-use-different-configuration-files-for-dev-prod?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a tutorial on [scala-sbt.org](https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/recipes/package_configuration.html) for `sbt-native-packager`, but got strange errors.

For moment, the only solution to use a different config file for a `sbt` project builded as `.bat` file is to specify the config file for starting command, how I specified above (`-Dconfig.resource=prod.conf`):

```
nohup ./path -J-Xms8g -J-Xmx8g -Dconfig.resource=prod.conf -Dhttp.port=7777</dev/null>>
```

So, first step is to use `sbt dist` to create the zip package without matter about config file. Then, unzip the file on server, and use command to start the application.

Answer (score 0):

the dist command does not take a config argument , therefore you are receiving the error not a valid command.
You can use a system property to specify a config file https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ConfigFile.
This allows you to have a different file loaded for your production environment